# Verifying proof for $\int_{0}^{T}|f(x)|^{2}dx\le\frac{T^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{T}|f'(x)|^{2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, fourier-series

> If $f$ is T-periodic , continuous and piecewise $C^{1}([0,T])$ with $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=0$
>
> then we have 
>   $$\int_{0}^{T}|f(x)|^{2}dx\le\frac{T^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{T}|f'(x)|^{2}dx$$

**My attempt :(edited)**

Firstly , we define the $n^{th}$ Fourier coefficient of $f$ on the $[0,T]$  by $\widehat{f}(n)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}f(x)e^{-\frac{2\pi i nx}{T}}~dx$ and denote that
$f\in L^{p}([0,T]),0<p<\infty~,$ if $\|f\|_{L^{p}([0,T])}=\bigg(\displaystyle\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}|f(x)|^{p}~dx\bigg)^{1/p}<\infty$ .

Now , as $f$ is piecewise $C^{1}$ on $[0,T]$ then $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,T]$ and hence for all $n\in{\bf Z}-\{0\}$ one has , $$\widehat{f'}(n)=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}f'(x)e^{-\frac{2\pi inx}{T}}dx=\frac{2\pi in}{T^{2}}\int_{0}^{T}f(x)e^{-\frac{2\pi inx}{T}}dx=\frac{2\pi in}{T}\widehat{f}(n)$$ , where the second equality used by  the integration by parts and $f(0)=f(T)$ as $f$ is T-periodic .

Moreover , we have that $\widehat{f'}(0)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}f'(x)~dx=\frac{1}{T}\big(f(T)-f(0)\big)=0\color{blue}{~~-(1)}$ .

As $f$ is continuous on $[0,T]$ , one must have $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and bounded on $[0,T]$ so we must have $f\in L^{2}([0,T])$ since $L^{1}([0,T])\cap L^{\infty}([0,T])$ is embedded into $L^{2}([0,T])$ .

Hence , by Parseval's identity that 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}|f(x)|^{2}dx&=T\sum_{n\in {\bf Z}}|\widehat{f}(n)|^{2}\\
&=T\sum_{n\ne 0}|\widehat{f}(n)|^{2}\\
&=\frac{T^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}T\sum_{n\ne 0}\frac{|{\widehat{f'}(n)}|^{2}}{\color{red}{n^{2}}}\\
&\le\frac{T^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}T\sum_{n\ne 0}|\widehat{f'}(n)|^{2}\\
&=\frac{T^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}T\sum_{n\in {\bf Z}}|\widehat{f'}(n)|^{2}\\
&=\frac{T^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{T}|f'(x)|^{2}dx
\end{align}
, where the second equality is according to the hypothesis that ${\widehat f}(0)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=0$ and the fourth equality holds by the equation $\color{blue}{(1)}$ .

Can anyone check my working for validity if you the time , otherwise just skip the post . Any comment or valuable suggestion I will be grateful .

**The red one is that I edited which is the suggestion by the user284331**

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14996/isoperimetric-inequality-implies-wirtingers-inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor mistake is that, one should have $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ne 0}|\widehat{f}(n)|^{2}=\sum_{n\ne 0}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}|\widehat{f'}(n)|^{2}\leq\sum|\widehat{f'}(n)|^{2}$.

Comment: oh....I put the wrong position for the variable $n$. Thanks for reminding me .